# Anded multiple tags do not work as expected in specflow

Tags: c#, msbuild, specflow

I have the following hook in my test project:

```
    [AfterScenario]
    [Scope(Tag = "Tag1"), Scope(Tag = "Tag2")]
    public static void AfterScenarioMethod()
    {
    }
```

Based on the SpecFlow documentation, I should expect to enter AfterFeatureMethod() only if the ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags includes both of the required tags. However, the method is executed even when only Tag1 is available.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First AfterScenario is not static.

If you define multiple properties on one attribute, they are combined with AND.
If you have multiple attributes, they are combined with OR.

From documentation: https://specflow.org/documentation/Scoped-Bindings/

> If multiple [Scope] attributes are defined for the same method or class, the attributes are combined with OR, i.e. at least one of the [Scope] attributes needs to match.

To check for multiple tags you have to do following:

```cs
[Binding]
public class Bindings
{
    private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

    public Bindings(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
         _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public static void AfterScenarioMethod()
    {
        if (_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Tag1") &&
            _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("Tag2") {
            //do you stuff
        }
    }

}
```

Code is written from memory, I didn't tried it out.